# Parallelise a for loop in a bash file

Tags: bash, parallelism, matlab

I would like to **parallelise** the for loop in the bash script below.

---

I have two  Matlab scripts

**1) main.m**

```
clear
rng default
P=2;
grid=randn(2,3);
jobs=1;
```

**2) f.m**

```
sgetasknum_grid=grid(jobs*(str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))-1)+1: str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))*jobs,:); %jobsx3

result=sgetasknum_grid+1; 

filename = sprintf('result.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename, 'result')

exit
```

**What I want to do:**

- I want to run main.m;
- then, I want to run f.m twice **in parallel**
- Everything should be executed on node **A**

---

Here's my version **without parallelising**

**1)** I save main.m and f.m into a folder named My_folder

**2)** I create the bash file td.sh as below and save it into the folder My_folder

```
    #$ -S /bin/bash
    #$ -l h_vmem=5G
    #$ -l tmem=5G
    #$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
    #$ -cwd
    #$ -j y


    #$ -N try

    date
    hostname

    export SGE_TASK_ID

    for SGE_TASK_ID in {1..2}
do
    #Output the Task ID
    echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

  /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID=$SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
done
```

**3)** I go into the terminal and type `ssh username@A`, then `cd /.../My_folder`, then `bash td.sh`

---

**In order to parallelise**, many answers in this forum suggests to use `parallel`. I guess the bash file would look something like the following

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=5G
#$ -l tmem=5G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y


#$ -N try

date
hostname

export SGE_TASK_ID

SGE_TASK_ID={1..2}

echo "$SGE_TASK_ID" | parallel -P 2 /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID=$SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

---

However, this is the error that I get on the terminal

```
A.local
td.sh: line 16: parallel: command not found
```

I understand that it may be that the `parallel` "software" is missing in the machine. Can I install it and if yes how? Or should it be installed by the sysadmins? Alternatively, do you have other recommendations instead of `parallel`?

---

Update: script that attempts to implement the second answer below

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=5G
#$ -l tmem=5G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y


#$ -N try

date
hostname

export SGE_TASK_ID

SGE_TASK_ID={1..2}

echo -e SGE_TASK_ID | xargs -I {} -P 4 /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash  -r "main; ID={}; f; exit"
```

And this is the error message that I get

```
Undefined function or variable 'SGE_TASK_ID'.
```

Comment: Doesn't Matlab itself allow concurrent execution (I don't know)?

Comment: For installing GNU Parallel see: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, start the Matlab jobs in the background, then wait for them to finish after the loop:

```
for SGE_TASK_ID in 1 2; do
    printf 'Task ID is %d\n' "$SGE_TASK_ID"

    /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash \
        -r "main; ID=$SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit" &
done

wait
```

The Matlab jobs will be started in quick succession and will run concurrently.  The `wait` after the loop ensures that the script does not exit until all background jobs are finished.

For `J` jobs where you are allowed to run `N` jobs in parallel:

```
SGE_TASK_ID=1
n=0
while [ "$SGE_TASK_ID" -le "$J" ]; do
    if [ "$n" -eq "$N" ]; then
        wait  # waits for the N started jobs to finish
        n=0
    fi

    printf 'Task ID is %d\n' "$SGE_TASK_ID"

    /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash \
        -r "main; ID=$SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit" &

    SGE_TASK_ID=$(( SGE_TASK_ID + 1 ))
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done

wait
```

Another variation is to wait for a *single* background job to finish inside the loop's `if`-statement, with `wait -n` and just decrease `n` by one instead of setting it to zero.

Comment: Thanks! I have a clarification to ask: suppose that I'm allowed to perform at most `N` tasks in parallel, but the number of iterations of my `for` loop is `J>N`. Is there a way to ask to execute `N` tasks in parallel and, as soon as one is finished, to "refill" it with a new task until the `J` tasks are all executed?

Comment: Also, the request of memory at the beginning of the bash file should be the amount of memory needed for each single task or in total?

Comment: @user3285148 See update answer. I would assume that the resource limits would be for the resources needed to run `N` jobs at once.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) ``# waits for the N started jobs to finish`` means that ALL the `N` tasks should finish before a new one starts. At the end of your answer you mention that we can start a new task as soon as one slot is free. Could you write the code exactly for this? Also, which solution is more efficient according to you: waiting for all the `N` tasks to finish or refilling as soon as one slot is free? (2) Is there any difference between your solution and  using `parallel` in terms of efficiency, speed, ...? (3) A silly question: suppose `J=2000` and `N=100`; where do I declare these values?

Comment: @user3285148 1) Yes, `wait` waits for _all_ background jobs to finish. Just change `wait` in the loop to `wait -n` and `n=0` to `n=$(( n - 1 ))` to wait for a single job to finish.  Leave `wait` _after_ the loop as it is. Wating for a single job to finish may be more efficient use of resources. 2) `parallel` (and `xargs`) are typically used to start or feed multiple background jobs with data from a file or command.  You could use them here too, but I don't really see a reason for it. 3) Somewhere above the loop.

Comment: Thanks. 3)  something like `J=2000 echo $J`?

Comment: @user3285148 No need to `echo` it, but if you do, put the `echo` on a new line.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run that but it gives me an error `td.sh: line 25: wait: -n: invalid option`. Even though at the end, it creates the mat files that I want.

Comment: @user3285148 That would indicate that the script is not being run by `bash`.

Comment: Thanks. What does that mean? What should I change? when I execute td.sh I type on the terminal `bash td.sh`: is this wrong?

Comment: @user3285148 It means that whatever shell the queuing system uses to run your job submission script is not `bash`, or at least not a version of `bash` that knows what `wait -n` means.  You could try adding a proper `#!/bin/bash`-line at the very top of the script (1st line, no space before the `#!`), and if that does not work, read the manual for the submission command that you use, or contact a system admin for more info.

Answer (score 1):

a slightly cleaner solution;

```
echo -e "1\n2" | xargs -I {} -P $(nproc) /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash  -r "main; ID={}; f; exit"
```

if you have more than 2 tasks

Comment: Thanks. Suppose that I'm allowed to perform at most `N` tasks in parallel, but the number of iterations of my for loop is `J>N`. Does your code allow to execute `N` tasks in parallel and, as soon as one is finished, to "refill" it with a new task until the `J` tasks are all executed? The other answer gave me that option too.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What are `N` and `J` in your code? (2) What do you mean by "a tool that comes with your OS" (sorry, I'm a very beginner, I don't know this terminology)?

Comment: Thanks. Where is `J` (number of iterations of the four loop)?

Comment: Not sure I'm implementing your code in the correct way. See the updated part of my answer

Comment: Thanks. But SGE_TASK_ID is in my f.m script...

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. See the updated part of my question.